# Installed Python and Django Using Chocolatey - How Do I Run Django?

Tags: python, django

Apologies if the answer seems obvious. I've installed Python3, Django, Git and an environment for said Python without a hitch. Now I'm unsure as to how I get Django up and running. I implemented a "C:>/workspace/local_sites" folder for my Django projects to be in, as seen below:

[local sites folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxsqo.png)

But I'm unsure as to where I go from here. Every tutorial I come across appears to be running Django through methods I cannot access since I used PowerShell to install the program rather than CmdPrompt. I just want to create a working, interactive website, that I can store in a folder and come back to whenever I please.

Again, apologies if the answer seems obvious. Thank you for your time.

NOTE:

Tried creating a Django project folder through powershell and the command prompt, both times I received this error:
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ django-admin startproject RottenJournalists
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Why does it matter if you used PowerShell or `cmd.exe`? I'm not on Windows, but I'd expect the [`django-admin` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/) to work the same either way.

Comment: Thank you, I dare say you are right. I'm just unsure where to go from here and I've found a lack of up-to-date tutorials.

Comment: How did you install Python and Django?

Comment: This may help you. [djangoproject](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Comment: Through chocolatey - a program manager, simple install through power shell - "choco install python3", then a pip install for Django after python fully installed.